# Set unicode into clipboard

Tags: java, clipboard, skype

I am trying to format several aspects of my clipboard when I set it. from what I understand I need to use DataFlavors and have done some reading on Oracle about it but am not sure if/how it is possible to set Unicode and other such formats. (XML?)

Answer (score 0):

[DocFlavor.CHAR_ARRAY](http://minitorn.tlu.ee/~jaagup/kool/java/abiinfo/docs7/api/javax/print/DocFlavor.CHAR_ARRAY.html) should do. This is Unicode in the form of UTF-16, which should congrue with wide chars on Windows. The problem probably is the normal EOM single byte character set that is default.